# Visual Studio Extension Laravel Eloquent Snippet Support?

Tags: laravel

Just wanted to know if or how I can have snippets for vscode for laravel eloquent typing.

Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of Laravel snippet packs already in the marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=laravel&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance

If none of these works, you can [create your own snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets)